# Facebook-style sliding widget

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, slider

I am new at Android Development, working in a personal application.

I want to implement a gallery-style widget in my app, something like the following facebook app screenshot (not enough reputation to upload images here) i. e. a swipeable and clickeable bunch of elements.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRsZU.jpg

I want every element of this gallery-like widget to be a composite layout (distinct instance of a fragment) with textView and imageView (I think I can figure how to do that) instead of a simple image.

I have a navigation drawer im my application and I'm using a "single activity-multiple fragment architecture", so I want to add this gallery-like widget in one of those fragments.

Please, If you could guide me or give me some suggestion about the Android layout elements I can use to accomplish that, I would be very happy :D

I'm aiming from API Level 15 to API Level 19, only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of reading several android tutorials, I realize the Widget I was looking for is the ViewPager

:D